# What is the use of Phantom key(shadow copy) in redis that is created by spring data redis?

Tags: spring-data-redis

I would like to understand the actual usage of the phantom key in the Redis that is created by Spring Data Redis through the Java Spring boot application.

It is mentioned in the spring boot help document as below. But still i am not able to understand the usage of the phantom key. I understand that the connected application will receive the key expiry event when the object is deleted or expired.  Can some one explain the use of the phantom key with the use case?

> When the expiration is set to a positive value, the corresponding EXPIRE command is run. In addition to persisting the original, a phantom copy is persisted in Redis and set to expire five minutes after the original one. This is done to enable the Repository support to publish RedisKeyExpiredEvent, holding the expired value in Spring’s ApplicationEventPublisher whenever a key expires, even though the original values have already been removed. Expiry events are received on all connected applications that use Spring Data Redis repositories.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/reference/redis/redis-repositories/expirations.html#page-title

The phantom key uses additional storage. I can disable the phantom keys by setting @EnableKeyspaceEvents(shadowCopy = OFF). But still, I don't what will be the problem if phantom keys are not created.